# How to replace CCSpriteSheet by CCSpriteBatchNode

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

So I have created a `CCSpriteSheet` :

```
_spriteSheet = [[CCSpriteSheet spriteSheetWithFile:@"deuximages2.png" capacity:2] retain];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"deuximages2.plist"];
```

in another method :

```
 mangeur = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"mangeurcentremieu_03.png"];
```

but I have the warning : `CCSpriteSheet is deprecated.` I think that I have to replace it by `CCSpriteBatchNode` but I don't know how to do it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CCSpriteBatchNode`](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_sprite_batch_node.html)'s interfaces are basically the same as [`CCSpriteSheet`](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_sprite_sheet.html). I remember `CCSpriteBatchNode` was introduced in 0.99.5 to replace `CCSpriteSheet`.

```
_batchNode = [[CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"deuximages2.png" capacity:2] retain];
```